# Building Qgis-1.8 on Scientific Linux - a sip error occured

Tags: qgis

I'm on Scientific Linux 6.3 and after trying to build Qgis 1.8 fter "ccmake" I got the error:

---

[ 89%] Built target translations
[ 89%] Generating analysis/sipanalysispart0.cpp, analysis/sipanalysispart1.cpp, analysis/sipanalysispart2.cpp, analysis/sipanalysispart3.cpp

sip: Usage: sip [-h] [-V] [-a file] [-c dir] [-d file] [-e] [-g] [-I dir] [-j #] [-m file] [-p module] [-r] [-s suffix] [-t tag] [-w] [-x feature] [-z file] [file]
make[2]: *** [python/analysis/sipanalysispart0.cpp] Error 1
make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_analysis.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

---

here's my ccmake configuration screen:

BINDINGS_GLOBAL_INSTALL          OFF
 BISON_EXECUTABLE                 /usr/bin/bison
 BUILD_TESTING                    ON
 CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE
 CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX             /usr/local
 DART_ROOT                        DART_ROOT-NOTFOUND
 ENABLE_TESTS                     ON
 EXPAT_INCLUDE_DIR                /usr/include
 EXPAT_LIBRARY                    /usr/lib64/libexpat.so
 FLEX_EXECUTABLE                  /usr/bin/flex
 GDAL_CONFIG                      /usr/local/bin/gdal-config
 GDAL_CONFIG_PREFER_FWTOOLS_PAT   /bin_safe
 GDAL_CONFIG_PREFER_PATH          /bin
 GDAL_INCLUDE_DIR                 /usr/local/include
 GDAL_LIBRARY                     /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so
 GEOS_CONFIG                      /usr/bin/geos-config
 GEOS_CONFIG_PREFER_PATH          /bin
 GEOS_INCLUDE_DIR                 /usr/include
GEOS_LIBRARY                     /usr/lib64/libgeos_c.so
 GEOS_LIB_NAME_WITH_PREFIX        -lgeos_c
 GITCOMMAND                       /usr/bin/git
 GIT_MARKER                       /home/tomas/Downloads/libspatialindex-master/
 GRASS_PREFIX                     /usr/local/grass-6.4.3svn
 GSL_CONFIG                       /usr/bin/gsl-config
 GSL_CONFIG_PREFER_PATH           /bin
 GSL_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS             -Wl,-rpath,
 PEDANTIC                         ON
 POSTGRESQL_PREFIX                /usr/pgsql-9.2
 POSTGRES_CONFIG                  /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin/pg_config
 POSTGRES_CONFIG_PREFER_PATH      /usr/pgsql-9.2/bin
 POSTGRES_INCLUDE_DIR             /usr/pgsql-9.2/include
 POSTGRES_LIBRARY                 /usr/pgsql-9.2/lib/libpq.so
 PROJ_INCLUDE_DIR                 /usr/include
 PROJ_LIBRARY                     /usr/lib64/libproj.so
 PYRCC4_PROGRAM                   /usr/bin/pyrcc4
 PYTHON_LIBRARY                   /usr/lib64/libpython2.6.so 
 PYUIC4_PROGRAM                   /usr/bin/pyuic4
 QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR           QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
 QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY               QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
 QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE              /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
 QWT_INCLUDE_DIR                  /usr/include/qwt
 QWT_LIBRARY                      /usr/lib64/libqwt.so
 SPATIALINDEX_INCLUDE_DIR         /usr/local/include/spatialindex
 SPATIALINDEX_LIBRARY             /usr/local/lib/libspatialindex.so
 SPATIALITE_INCLUDE_DIR           SPATIALITE_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
 SPATIALITE_LIBRARY               SPATIALITE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
 SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR              /usr/include
 SQLITE3_LIBRARY                  /usr/lib64
 TXT2TAGS_EXECUTABLE              TXT2TAGS_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
 WITH_APIDOC                      OFF
 WITH_ASTYLE                      OFF
 WITH_BINDINGS                    ON
 WITH_DESKTOP                     ON
 WITH_GLOBE                       OFF 
 PYUIC4_PROGRAM                   /usr/bin/pyuic4
 QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR           QSCINTILLA_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
 QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY               QSCINTILLA_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
 QT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE              /usr/bin/qmake-qt4
 QWT_INCLUDE_DIR                  /usr/include/qwt
 QWT_LIBRARY                      /usr/lib64/libqwt.so
 SPATIALINDEX_INCLUDE_DIR         /usr/local/include/spatialindex
 SPATIALINDEX_LIBRARY             /usr/local/lib/libspatialindex.so
 SPATIALITE_INCLUDE_DIR           SPATIALITE_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
 SPATIALITE_LIBRARY               SPATIALITE_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
 SQLITE3_INCLUDE_DIR              /usr/include
 SQLITE3_LIBRARY                  /usr/lib64
 TXT2TAGS_EXECUTABLE              TXT2TAGS_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
 WITH_APIDOC                      OFF
 WITH_ASTYLE                      OFF
 WITH_BINDINGS                    ON
 WITH_DESKTOP                     ON
 WITH_GLOBE                       OFF 
WITH_GRASS                       ON
 WITH_INTERNAL_QEXTSERIALPORT     ON
 WITH_INTERNAL_QWTPOLAR           ON
 WITH_INTERNAL_SPATIALITE         ON
 WITH_MAPSERVER                   OFF
 WITH_POSTGRESQL                  ON
 WITH_PYSPATIALITE                OFF
 WITH_PY_COMPILE                  OFF
 WITH_QSCIAPI                     ON
 WITH_QTMOBILITY                  OFF
 WITH_SPATIALITE                  OFF
 WITH_STAGED_PLUGINS              ON
 WITH_TOUCH                       OFF
 WITH_TXT2TAGS_PDF                OFF
 _find_lib_python_py              /home/tomas/Downloads/libspatialindex-master/
 _find_pyqt_py                    /home/tomas/Downloads/libspatialindex-master/
 _find_qsci_py                    /home/tomas/Downloads/libspatialindex-master/
 _find_sip_py                     /home/tomas/Downloads/libspatialindex-master/

Comment: Maybe this will be of help: http://www.surfaces.co.il/?p=1260

Comment: You can get more information out of cmake generated makefiles by something like "VERBOSE=1 make" or similar.